# KineticJS - Collision detection between shapes

Tags: collision-detection, kineticjs, shapes

I would like to know how i can detect collision between shapes instead of getting a list wit intersecting objects or point in path. Just 2 (or more) shapes colliding detection.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any method inside the kineticjs framework that do collision detection( please prove me wrong).

So your back to do it with standard techniques found
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection)
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158/resources-of-techniques-use-for-collision-detection-in-2d)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will have a look. I come from flash/actionscriot. With flash there was the possibility to do that, so i hope someone has a kineticjs solution :-)